# ejabberd clustering with multiple regions

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have just set ejabberd on CentOS and I want to make it redundant. It is set to use .htpasswd like file for auth (I am planning to integrate auth with LDAP) and mnesia for other metadata.

I am reading on ejabberd documentation on clustering but they suggest nodes to be essentially in same datacenter. 
My initial plan was to set west coast and east coast instances and cluster them. Is this possible? If so, can someone direct me where to read on this?

Now I am thinking about setting two instances on west coast and two instances on east coast and cluster everything and utilize Anycast? Does that make sense?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to deploy ejabberd Community Edition across several region. ejabberd cluster rely on Mnesia database synchronisation. Latency will slow down your system and netsplits will require manual intervention to solve the issues / conflicts.

It may work, but it will be less reliable than putting all your nodes in the same data center, to match the design of that version of ejabberd.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think if running two ejabberd nodes in same datacenter but in different hypervisors in cluster makes more sense?